# Having problems with velodyne VLP-16 and ros

Tags: ros, vlp-16, ubuntu, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS and Linux so my question may be very stupid. Sorry for that.

I want to connect VLP-16 and laptop (in fact i need to connect it with raspberry pi, but i first wanna try it on laptop). I tryed to use tutorial "Getting Started with the Velodyne HDL-32E". I wasn't surprise that I fail with it. So I tryed to solve problems in different ways but i didn't succeed. So i decide to write post here.

Maybe i should solve problems step by step.

So. Could someone explain how should I work with velodyne driver and VLP-16 and how can I find out my VPL-16 ip on Ubuntu?

I use Ubuntu 12 and ros "fuerte". On raspberry I would use "indigo" instead.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

---

Hi again. Ty for your help. Now i build velodyne_driver from source but I still don't scceed.

First in tutorial "Getting Started with the Velodyne HDL-32E" I need to do that steps:

> Power the LIDAR via the included
> adapter
> Connect the LIDAR to an Ethernet port on your computer.
> Statically assign an IP to this port in the 192.168.3.x range.
>
> ```
> sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100
> ```
>
> Add a static route to the LIDAR's IP address. The IP address can be
> found on the CD case which was
> included with the LIDAR.
>
> ```
>  sudo route add 192.168.XX.YY eth0
> ```

How could I find what XX and YY should be? I don't have any CD included.

And after that. How could I know are my ip settings set correctly (look any data on my laptop recived by VLP-16)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244445/having-problems-with-velodyne-vlp-16-and-ros/) by [Mortivor](https://answers.ros.org/users/28044/mortivor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know the standard address of the VLP-16 is 192.168.1.201.
So what I'd do is:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

`sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.200 dev eth0`

`sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0`

Afterwards you should have access to the vlps webinterface via your browser. Then run the vlp driver, and make sure the rpms set in driver and webinterface match.

---

Originally posted by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) with karma: 365 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mortivor](https://answers.ros.org/users/28044/mortivor/) on 2016-10-18**:
I did all as you recommend. After that I tryed to enter in my browser 192.168.1.200 or 192.168.1.201 and it said that it "Unable to connect".

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2016-10-20**:
saw in your other topic that you are using a vm. That would have been valueable information ;).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the wiki: Support for the VLP-16 was added in indigo, but it hasn't made it into the apt-get binaries yet. There is a tutorial on building from source.

http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1